# Character index to and from byte index

Tags: java, unicode, character-encoding

I know how to convert a character string into a byte array using a particular encoding, but how do I convert the character indexes to byte indexes (in Java)?

For instance, in UTF-32, character index `i` is byte index `4 * i` because every UTF-32 character is 4 bytes wide.  But in UTF-8, most English characters are 1 byte wide, characters in most other scripts are 2 or 3 bytes wide, and a few are 4 bytes wide.  For a given string and encoding, how would I get an array of starting byte indexes for each character?

Here's an example of what I mean.  The string `"Hello مرحبا こんにちは"` in UTF-8 has the following indexes: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 17, 20, 23, 26, 29]` because the Latin characters are 1 byte each, the Arabic characters are 2 bytes each, and the Japanese characters are 3 bytes each.  (Before the cumulative sum, the array is `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]`.)

Is there a library function in Java that computes these index positions?  It needs to be efficient, so I shouldn't convert each character to a separate byte array just to query its length.  Is there an easy way to compute it myself, from some knowledge of Unicode?  It should be possible to do in one pass, by recognizing special bytes that indicate the width of the next character.

Comment: You're asking two separate questions here - one about Python and one about Java.  It would be better to ask them separately, so you can "accept" the best answer to each one.

Comment: Okay, in this question, I'll just ask about and accept answers about Java.  Python information in a comment would just be a welcome bonus.

Comment: OK, are you aware that in Java, all strings are stored internally in UTF-16?

Comment: You're normally "doing it wrong" if you get here... (overwhelmingly, you should decode data as soon as you read it, and encode it at the last possible point)...

Comment: ps: if you must, then the Description section of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8 will give you the info needed to parse utf-8 into Unicode characters...

Comment: You need to decide whether your "character" indexes refer to real Unicode characters or to the UTF-16 code units used for indexing strings in Java. Neither is good. The real Unicode character indexes are difficult to use because they don't correspond to anything in Java, and the UTF-16 code units might not *have* a specific byte index in the UTF-8 byte data because they encode only part of a character.

Comment: I'm using a library that does extended POSIX regular expressions on byte arrays--- it has no concept of a Java `String`--- and it returns matches as indexes of the byte array.  One option is to `str.getBytes("utf-32be")` and divide all indexes it gives me by 4.  I'd like to use Java's internal encoding (utf-16be?) for efficiency, in which the factor is usually--- but not always--- 2.  I want it to always work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this can do what you want:

```
static int[] utf8ByteIndexes(String s) {
    int[] byteIndexes = new int[s.length()];
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        byteIndexes[i] = sum;
        int c = s.codePointAt(i);
        if (Character.charCount(c) == 2) {
            i++;
            byteIndexes[i] = sum;
        }
        if (c <=     0x7F) sum += 1; else
        if (c <=    0x7FF) sum += 2; else
        if (c <=   0xFFFF) sum += 3; else
        if (c <= 0x1FFFFF) sum += 4; else
        throw new Error();
    }
    return byteIndexes;
}
```

Given a Java string, it returns an array of the UTF-8 byte indexes corresponding to each `char` in the String.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(utf8ByteIndexes("Hello مرحبا こんにちは")));
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 17, 20, 23, 26, 29]
```

Exotic Unicode characters above U+FFFF, those that don't fit in Java's 16-bit char type, are a bit of a nuisance. For example, Christmas tree emoji U+1F384 ([image]) is encoded using two Java "chars". For those, the function above returns the same byte index for both chars:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(utf8ByteIndexes("xy")));
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 1, 5]
```

The overall cumulative byte count is correct though (the emoji takes 4 bytes if encoded in UTF-8).

Comment: Oh +1 for sneaking in a  in your answer! ! It must be Christmas!

Comment: I learned a few things from this.  One is that some code points are represented by two Java `String` indexes: I'd have thought that `"xy"` would be 3 characters long, rather than 4.  (It's 3 characters long in Python, for instance.)  Your Christmas tree illustrates an important special case.  Thanks!

Comment: One solution to the supplementary characters problem is to replace your loop with `for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i = s.offsetByCodePoints(i, 1))`.

Comment: @VGR The main issue is not how to write the loop, but how to give useful meaning to the array elements corresponding to UTF-16 code units. For example, `"".charAt(1)` represents half a character, and it's meaningless to ask about what happens if we take half a character and encode it in UTF-8. The function can be modified to generate an array of byte indexes corresponding to real Unicode characters instead of Java's UTF-16 code units, but then the result is more difficult to use as there is not an easy 1-to-1 correspondence between Java string indexes and indexes in the array.

Comment: @JimPivarski: it depends on what you are counting - and *how*  The reason Java gets it 'wrong' is because Unicode allows encoding a value larger than 0xFFFF as *two* characters, which is not a Java operation but perfectly valid in Unicode. Look up "surrogate pairs" for the details. Python may just be 'aware' of that. For a certain value of "length", both interpretations are correct...

Comment: @Jongware: In my comment, I didn't say it was wrong (though I was thinking that). A character/glyph/letter/symbol is an abstraction, distinct from the number of bytes to represent it--- thus, it's one string index and four byte indexes in Python.  It seems like Java is only going halfway with this, making a String-vs-byte[] distinction for most of Unicode (everything but the supplemental tables), but there's an exception for supplemental tables.

Comment: @Jongware: Since I started looking into this, I'm starting to find bugs in some libraries when supplemental table characters are involved.  For instance, avro-1.7.7.jar is writing that Christmas tree as 3 bytes, not 4, and it's supposed to be encoding in UTF-8!  (When I figure out what's going on, I'm going to be writing them some bug reports.)  The two `String` indexes per supplemental characters might be a source of confusion, though I understand why it can't be changed.

Comment: @JimPivarski "It seems like Java is only going halfway with this" Indeed but Java can't be blamed. The Unicode Consortium had declared that 16 bits (characters up to U+FFFF) should be enough for everybody. Java came out in 1995, with its Strings and chars designed around that 16-bit limit, which was really quite progressive for the time. In 1996, the Unicode Consortium decided they actually wanted space for another million or so characters, and there was no good way to make that work with the existing Java APIs. And yes, many applications don't handle it properly.